# Is there a way to reuse cucumber steps from multiple projects, in another project?

Tags: spring, kotlin, cucumber, cucumber-jvm

I have 2 microservices, A and B, which have cucumber tests defined for them in their own projects.

Service A

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes = [AppConfiguration::class])
class ServiceAStepDefs @Autowired constructor(private var serviceAProfile: ServiceAProfile) : En {
    //stepdefs live here
}
```

```
class AppConfiguration {

    @Bean
    fun serviceAProfileMaker(): ServiceAEnvironmentProfile {
        val oktaConfig = DefaultOAuth2Config.getToken()
        return ProfileManager.getEnvProfile(token)
    }

}
```

Service B

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes = [AppConfiguration::class])
class ServiceBStepDefs {
    //stepdefs live here
}
```

```
@ComponentScan("com.hello.*")
class AppConfiguration {

    @Bean
    fun serviceBProfileMaker(): ServiceBEnvironmentProfile {
        val token = DefaultOAuth2Config.getToken()
        return ProfileManager.getEnvProfile(token)
    }
}
```

In another project, C, I want to test these 2 services together. In order to do this I have created a jar file containing the step definitions for each of the services and pulled them into the project C as dependencies.

When I try to run a cucumber tests from project C, using steps from service A and service B, I am seeing an issue where the Spring Context is being picked up in both projects, which I guess is correct.

```
10:17:59.936 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]     io.cucumber.core.backend.CucumberBackendException: Glue class class com.hello.serviceA.stepdefs.ServiceASteps and class com.hello.stepdefs.ServiceBSteps both attempt to configure the spring context. Please ensure only one glue class configures the spring context
```

Is there a way for me to wire up these 2 services so that I can get the Beans configured up for both and reuse the steps?

Answer (score 0):

When using `cucumber-spring` Cucumber uses Spring's `TestContextManager` framework. This framework starts a test context using a single class. This class is checked for any annotations that configure the application context such as `@ContextConfiguration`.

Since both step definitions have this annotation Cucumber can't decide which to use and you'll get the error complaining about this. To resolve this you should ensure that only one glue class has the `@ContextConfiguration` annotation.

Cucumber v5.6.0 added the `@CucumberContextConfiguration` which made this a bit easier to do.

So you may want to structure your projects like this:

```java
a
|- config
| | AConfiguration with `@CucumberContextConfiguration` and `@ContextConfiguration(...)`
| | RunCucumberTest with `@CucumberOptions(extraGlue="a.steps")`
|- steps
| | ASteps

b
|- config
| | BConfiguration with `@CucumberContextConfiguration` and `@ContextConfiguration(...)`
| | RunCucumberTest with `@CucumberOptions(extraGlue="b.steps")`
|- steps
| | BSteps

c
|- config
| | CConfiguration with `@CucumberContextConfiguration` and `@ContextConfiguration(...)`
| | RunCucumberTest with `@CucumberOptions(extraGlue={"a.steps", "b.steps"})`
```

See: https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/tree/main/spring